# skip dbt model if source table not exist

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I am trying to force dbt to skip a model if source table was not found, but I didn't found any resources that could help on such topic, for more detail on the context, I have a folder called `sales` on which let's suppose we have two model `orders` and `customers`, the sql code inside each model is simply looking this way :

`select * from my_project.my_dataset.table`

Now the thing to mention is that `table` is just a temporary table in BigQuery that gets expired and renewed with new data continuously, so sometimes it exists in the dataset, but sometimes not. With that said, dbt when trying to run the model will throw an error cause he didn't find the table in the source, and that's fine I just want dbt to skip it and don't throw an error of `Table not Found`

Any approaches how to deal with this ?

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about BQ temp tables but if it is currently "expired" is that indicated in the information_schema anywhere? Does the row drop from the information_schema when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Looks like there might be an option here with the [TABLE_OPTIONS_VIEW](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_options_view), specifically for the `expiration_timestamp` value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a table that's logging database write/delete actions? Or a table that is tracking current tables that exist in your db? [let's call this an audit table]

If you do, then you could have a dbt query start by reading off that query and evaluating a single value from that table. If the value is not null or you get the expected number of tables return the go ahead and evaluate the rest of the sql. Otherwise have it be a sql query that does nothing.

You can use case logic for playing around with variables that store your sql, and set them to evaluate to empty strings when your desired table isn't listed in your audit table.